# Prob. 9 (b), Sec. 2.3, in Herstein's TOPICS IN ALGEBRA, 2nd ed: Every group of order $4$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Here is Prob. 9, Sec. 3.3, in the book *Topics in Algebra* by I.N. Herstein, 2nd edition:

> (a) If the group $G$ has three elements, show it must be abelian.
>
> (b) Do part (a) if $G$ has four elements.
>
> (c) Do part (a) if $G$ has five elements.

I think I am clear on how to tackle Part (a).

So here I will only be attempting Part (b).

My Attempt:

> Suppose our group $G$ has four distinct elements, say, $e, a, b, c$, with $e$ being the identity element.
>
> Now suppose, if possible, that $ab \neq ba$.
>
> As the elements $e, a, b, c$ of $G$ are all distinct, so by virtue of the cancellation laws (i.e. Lemma 2.3.2 in Herstein), we cannot have $ab = a$, $ab = b$, $ba = a$, or $ba = b$.
>
> Therefore we must $ab, ba \in \{ e, c \}$.
>
> Since $ab \neq ba$ according to our supposition, there we can assume without any loss of generality that $ab = c$ and $ba = e$.
>
> Thus our group $G$ has the four distinct elements $e, a, b, ab$.
>
> Since $ba = e$, we also have
>   $$ a = ae = a(ba). \tag{1} $$
>
> However, since $G$ is a group, we must have 
>   $$ a(ba) = (ab)a. \tag{2} $$
>
> From (1) and (2) above, we obtain
>   $$ a = (ab)a, $$
>   from which we obtain
>   $$ e = ab, $$
>   again by Lemma 2.3.2 in Herstein. This contradicts the fact that $e$ and $ab$ are two distinct elements of $G$. So our supposition that $ab \neq ba$ is wrong. Therefore we must have 
>   $$ ab = ba. $$
>
> An analogous argument yield $bc = cb$ and also  $ca = ac$.
>
> Thus any two of the elements $a, b, c$ of $G$ commute. And, the identity element $e$ of course commutes with itself as well as with each of $a$, $b$, and $c$.
>
> Hence our group $G$ must be abelian.

Is this proof correct? If so, is it rigorous enough for Herstein? Or, are there problems and issues?

Answer (score 2):

Yes your proof in fact is correct. But here are a few possible shorthands. First you only need to work with one non commuting pair of elements:

Suppose $G$ is not abelian, then there is some pair $a,b\in G$ such that: $ab\ne ba$. (We then can conclude that $a,b\ne e$). As you then found out: $ab,ba\in\{e,c\}$ for the fourth element $c\ne e,a,b$. So either $ab=e$ or $ab=c$ resulting in $ba=e$ (otherwise $a$ and $b$ commute and we are done). So in particular $a$ and $b$ are inverse elements to one another and hence commute. A contradiction. $G$ is abelian!

But you proof is just fine! :) Also nice effort of writing it down!