# Prob. 9 (c), Sec. 2.3, in Herstein's TOPICS IN ALGEBRA, 2nd ed: Every group of order $5$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Here is Prob. 9, Sec. 3.3, in the book *Topics in Algebra* by I.N. Herstein, 2nd edition:

> (a) If the group $G$ has three elements, show it must be abelian.
>
> (b) Do part (a) if $G$ has four elements.
>
> (c) Do part (a) if $G$ has five elements.

I think I am clear on how to tackle Part (a).

And, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403088/prob-9b-sec-2-3-in-hersteins-topics-in-algebra-2nd-ed-every-group-of-or) is my Mathematics Stack Exchange post on Part (b).

So here I will only be attempting Part (c).

My Attempt:

> Suppose our group $G$ has five distinct elements, say, $e, a, b, c, d$, with $e$ being the identity element.
>
> Now suppose, if possible, that $ab \neq ba$.
>
> As the elements $e, a, b, c, d$ of $G$ are all distinct, so by virtue of the cancellation laws (i.e. Lemma 2.3.2 in Herstein), we cannot have $ab = a$, $ab = b$, $ba = a$, or $ba = b$.
>
> Therefore we must $ab, ba \in \{ e, c, d \}$.
>
> Since $ab \neq ba$ by our supposition, therefore without loss of generality we have the following two cases:
>
> Case 1. Suppose that $ab = c$ [Or, we can also have $ab = d$.] and $ba = e$.
>
> Thus our group $G$ has the five distinct elements $e, a, b, ab, d$.
>
> Since $ba = e$, we also have
>   $$ a = ae = a(ba). \tag{1} $$
>
> However, since $G$ is a group, we must have 
>   $$ a(ba) = (ab)a. \tag{2} $$
>
> From (1) and (2) above, we obtain
>   $$ a = (ab)a, $$
>   from which we obtain
>   $$ e = ab, $$
>   again by Lemma 2.3.2 in Herstein. This contradicts the fact that $e$ and $ab$ are two *distinct* elements of $G$. So our supposition that $ab \neq ba$ is wrong. Therefore we must have 
>   $$ ab = ba. $$
>
> Case 2. Suppose that $ab = c$ and $ba = d$. [Or, vice versa.]
>
> Then our group $G$ has the five distinct elements $e, a, b, ab, ba$.
>
> By Lemma 2.3.2 in Herstein, $a^2$ cannot equal $a$ (for otherwise $a$ would equal $e$, which is contrary to our choice), nor can $a^2$ equal $ab$ or $ba$ (for otherwise $a$ would equal $b$, again contrary to our choice). So we must have $a^2 = b$ or $a^2 = e$. However, if $a^2 = b$, then we obtain
>   $$ ab = aa^2 = a^3 = a^2a = ba, $$
>   which is contrary to our supposition that $ab \neq ba$. So we must have $a^2 = e$, which implies that $a^{-1} = a$. Similarly, we also have $b^2 = e$, which implies that $b^{-1} = b$.
>
> Therefore we have
>   $$ (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = ba. \tag{3} $$
>
> Now consider $(ab)a$.  By the closure property of our group $G$, $(ab)a$ must be one of the elements $e, a, b, ab, ba$. However we show in the following paragraphs that each of these possibilities leads to a contradiction.
>
> We note that if $(ab)a = e$, then $(ab)^{-1} =a$, and thus from (3) above (and the uniqueness of the inverse of each element in a group) we obtain $ba = a$, a contradiction. So $$ (ab)a \neq e. $$
>
> If $(ab)a = a$, then we obtain $ab = e$, a contradiction. So $$ (ab)a \neq a. $$
>
> If $(ab)a = b$, then we obtain 
>   $$ ab = abe = aba^2 = [(ab)a]a = ba, $$
>   again a contradiction to our supposition that $ab \neq ba$. So 
>   $$ (ab)a \neq b. $$
>
> If $(ab)a = ab$, then we obtain $a = e$, a contradiction. So $$ (ab)a \neq ab.$$
>
> Finally, if $$ (ab)a = ba, $$
>   then we obtain $$ a(ba) = ba, $$
>   which implies
>   $$ a = e, $$
>   a contradiction. So $$ (ab)a \neq ba.$$
>
> Thus we have shown that, in either of Cases 1 and 2 above, our supposition that $ab \neq ba$ has led to contradictions. So we must have $$ ab = ba. $$
>
> An analogous argument yields $bc = cb$, $bd = db$, $ac = ca$, $cd = dc$.
>
> Thus any two of the elements $a, b, c, d$ of $G$ commute. And, the identity element $e$ of course commutes with itself as well as with each of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.
>
> Hence our group $G$ is indeed abelian.

Is this proof correct? If so, is it rigorous enough for Herstein? Or, are there problems and issues?

Comment: Seems correct, but since the proof is long, maybe I did not notice something. Also, you can show that $|G| = 5$ implies $G$ cyclic and so, working with the generator, is easiest to show that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: I haven't looked at your attempt. Let me ask though: are you allowed to use Lagrange's theorem? If yes, then a proof for part c) is much easier.

Comment: Even without Lagrange, you can simplify quite a bit your proof by observing that in a group $xy=e \Rightarrow y=x^{-1} \Rightarrow yx=e$$ Therefore, you can skip case 1.

Comment: @the_fox Lagrange's theorem has yet to come. So a proof without recourse to that result is desired.

Comment: @Corrêa that is a consequence of the Lagrange's theorem, a result which is not to be used at this stage since the Lagrange theorem has not yet been discussed by Herstein.

Comment: There seems to be a simple proof: Since G is of prime order (order is 5), must be cyclic. And cyclic group is abelian.

Comment: @fzyzcjy that fact is not on offer yet, for subgroups are the topic of the next section in the book. Please note the title of the post.

Comment: Ah ok I did not noticed that